# What does signal 15 mean

Tags: python, heroku, fastapi

I have this error after deploying my fastapi app on heroku. it say app terminated due to signal 15. Can someone help me out.

```
2021-12-03T12:17:35.623624+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-03 12:17:35 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2021-12-03T12:17:35.623625+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-03 12:17:35 +0000] [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)
2021-12-03T12:17:36.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-12-03T12:17:36.626062+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-03 12:17:36 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 10 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-12-03T12:17:36.629487+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-03 12:17:36 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 9 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-12-03T12:17:36.643503+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-03 12:17:36 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 11 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-12-03T12:17:36.715299+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-03 12:17:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-12-03T12:17:36.715450+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-12-03 12:17:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-12-03T12:17:36.865607+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-12-03T12:17:37.090747+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Comment: Is that *all* of the logs? Are there no other errors related to the app?

Comment: Signal 15 is SIGTERM and it's gunicorn terminating the worker because the application didn't start properly. there is nothing in this log that tells you why _that_ is the case, however.

Comment: @GinoMempin Thats all of the error logs. should i share my folder structure

Comment: @MatsLindh should i share my folder structure and my Procfile if you can detect whats causing it?

Comment: How did you get these logs? I think these are just the last few lines of the entire logs. Try redeploying and immediately recheck the logs, because it might have been trimmed. Also a [mcve] of the app would help.

Comment: The same things happens when I start my app with gunicorn. There is no error message indicating why it got signal 15. I can start it by hand with the flask runner. I'll have to look at gunicorn source code to see what it's doing.

Comment: not sure if it is the same issue, but I am trying to run FastAPI on CPanel using Asgi2 and getting '''child process killed with signal 15''' and from what I am seeing it is to do with the fact I am runnning in a subdomain. where in the folder structure you have your code may matter. One solution - not for me - was to move the code up a folder level.